# Does Django allow one to define different set of fields for each document in MongoDB?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

### Django and MongoDB

Supporting a `different set of fields for each document in a collection` is one of MongoDB's features. It allows you to store similar data, but with different properties in the same collection.

for example:

```
{
        _id: ObjectId("51156a1e056d6f966f268f81"),
        type: "Article",
        author: "Derick Rethans",
        title: "Introduction to Document Databases with MongoDB",
        date: ISODate("2013-04-24T16:26:31.911Z"),
        body: "This arti…"
},
{
        _id: ObjectId("51156a1e056d6f966f268f82"),
        type: "Book",
        author: "Derick Rethans",
        title: "php|architect's Guide to Date and Time Programming with PHP",
        isbn: "978-0-9738621-5-7"
}
```

Django dose not support Non-Relational data base like mongodb by default, but there are some lib's for this purpose. for example [Django MongoDB Engine](https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a MongoDB backend for Django.

MongoDB allow to use different set of fields for each document in a collection, but in django you have to define `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = ListField()
    comments = ListField()
```

the Question is: is there any way to define different set of fields for each document in a collection in MongoDB, when using Django ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Alternative

I like using [django-mongoengine](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine) as it makes things clearer when dealing with MongoDB models.

For example, you can create structured `Document`s that are going to be transformed into models or `Embedded`Document`s that are structured documents to be used in an already existed model.

```
from django_mongoengine import Document, EmbeddedDocument, fields

class Comment(EmbeddedDocument):
    created_at = fields.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.datetime.now, editable=False,
    )
    author = fields.StringField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255)
    email  = fields.EmailField(verbose_name="Email")
    body = fields.StringField(verbose_name="Comment")

class Post(Document):
    created_at = fields.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.datetime.now, editable=False,
    )
    title = fields.StringField(max_length=255)
    slug = fields.StringField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    comments = fields.ListField(
        fields.EmbeddedDocumentField('Comment'), blank=True,
    )
```

### The Answer

So for your case what you need to use is [Dynamic document schemas](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html#dynamic-document-schemas) that work in the same way as Document but any data/attributes set to them will also be saved.

```
class Page(DynamicDocument):
    title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True)

# Create a new page and add tags
>>> page = Page(title='Using MongoEngine')
>>> page.tags = ['mongodb', 'mongoengine']
>>> page.save()

>>> Page.objects(tags='mongoengine').count()
>>> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled this problem in user profile page. This is my solution.

**model.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model): 


    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name="user_profile")
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="full name")     
    about = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
    hobies = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    recent_aktivity = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name="recent activity",null=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to="images/")
    recent_badges = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name="recent badges",null=True)
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone_number = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17, blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="phone number") 
    website_url = models.URLField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name="company website")
    projects =models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300,blank=True,null=True)
    
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}-ProfileModel'
```

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user =instance)
```

**app.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProfileConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'Profile'

    def ready(self):
        import Profile.signals
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from.models import Profile



class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):   
        
    
      class Meta:
          model = Profile
          fields = '__all__'
          exclude = ['user']
```

**views.py**

```
 from django.contrib import messages
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.urls.base import reverse
    from .forms import ProfileForm
    from .models import Profile
    from django.shortcuts import redirect, render,get_object_or_404
    from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
    
    login_required(login_url="user:login")
    def dashboard(request):
        return render(request,"dashboard.html")
    
    
    @login_required(login_url="user:login")
    def get_profile(request):    
        
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,user=request.user)
        
    return render(request,"profile.html",{"profile":profile})
```